# Organização de diretórios no framework Silex

Tags: php, silex

Alguém sabe algum link para começar com esse microframework, eu procurei mas só acho em inglês e não está completo, só mostra a parte de instalação. Estou com dificuldade na montagem da estrutura de pastas: controllers, models.

Minha estrutura:

```
vendor
->(...)versão fat
web
->index.php
->views/
-->base.twig
-->index.twig
```

Consegui chamar views pelo twig até o momento, quem poder me ajudar agradeço.
Valeu!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O Silex não exige nenhuma estrutura de diretórios, você é livre para utilizar o que mais te agrada, o que é mais adequado para o projeto. Se por um lado essa liberdade é boa (o Silex não te impõe nada que não pareça natural no projeto), ela também é ruim (o Silex não te induz a organizar bem o seu projeto).

Então está nas suas mãos decidir como organizar os diretórios. Encontrei [um artigo interessante sobre o assunto](http://php-and-symfony.matthiasnoback.nl/2012/01/silex-getting-your-project-structure-right/), com uma sugestão de organização. Se souber inglês, é uma boa leitura.

Comment: Valeu pela ajuda!